# Object like a list or dict

Tags: python, class

i Have a class `Vertex` like:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,key):
        self.id = key
        self.connectedTo = {}
        self.neighbors = {}
        
        self.dict = {}
        
        self.community = []
        
        self.inside = 0
        self.been = 0
```

and I want to put all those selfs `community, inside, been, (...)` and some more attributes in one dictionary that will be iterable so:

```
vertex['inside'] = 0
```

Right now some of my attributes are in `self.dict` so I'm using for example: `vertex.dict['visited'] = 1` but can I skip `.dict` and write it as `vertex['visited'] = 1`?

Comment: Define `__getitem__` for your class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__dict__` on an instance of `Vertex`

```
vertex = Vertex(1)
d = vertex.__dict__
d['visited'] = 1
print(vertex.visited) # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **getitem** and **setitem** methode like :

```
class Vertex:
def __init__(self,key):
    ...
    self.data = {'community':self.community, ...}

def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.data[key]

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = value
```

Need to find something else for the setitem method this is not going to work perfectly here, it was just an example, but the getitem will work for sure.

Why it will not work :

```
class Vertex:
def __init__(self,key):
    self.a = 4
    self.data = {'a': self.a}
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.data[key]
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.data[key] = value
```

then :

```
>>> t = Vertex(1)
>>> t['a']
4
>>> t['a'] = 3
>>> t['a']
3
>>> t.a
4
```

The value in the dict will be updated but not the attribute

Comment: why its not going to work well here? I tried it and seems to work

Comment: Because if you do (assuming vert1 is an instance) vert1['community'] = newcommunity. The value in the vert1.data will change but vert1.community will not be changed. Don't know if I'm clear. I'll add an example to my response

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like that by overriding the special methods associated with accessing the elements as illustrated below:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, key):
        super().__setattr__('_dict', {})
        self['id'] = key
        self['connectedTo'] = {}
        self['neighbors'] = {}
        self['community'] = []
        self['inside'] = 0
        self['been'] = 0

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dict[key] = value

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        _dict = super().__getattribute__('_dict')
        _dict[name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        _dict = super().__getattribute__('_dict')
        return _dict[name]


vertex = Vertex(42)
print('Upon creation:')
print(f'{vertex._dict=}')
vertex.community.append((1,2,3))
vertex.inside = 17
vertex.connectedTo['foobar'] = 20210613
print()
print('After modifications:')
print(f'{vertex._dict=}')
```

Output:

```
Upon creation:
vertex._dict={'id': 42, 'connectedTo': {}, 'neighbors': {}, 'community': [], 'inside': 0, 'been': 0}

After modifications:
vertex._dict={'id': 42, 'connectedTo': {'foobar': 20210613}, 'neighbors': {}, 'community': [(1, 2, 3)], 'inside': 17, 'been': 0}
```